# Open link in a new window with javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I want to open links in a new pop up, I have my link in a PHP Code but when I try to add a on-click I keep getting errors.

This is my code:

```
echo "<td><a href=\"edit.php?id=$row[id]\">Edit</a></td>";
```

Where exactly do I need to add the on-click function? Because it's easy in html but I keep getting errors because it's in PHP

Thanks

Comment: Add `target="_blank"` as a property on the `a` element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add **target="_blank"**

> _blank : Opens the linked document in a new window or tab

```
echo "<td><a href=\"edit.php?id=$row[id]\" target='_blank'>Edit</a></td>";
```

For a popup solution add this (attention to the various " ' )

```
target="popup" onclick="window.open('yourlink','name','width=xxx,height=xxx')"
```

Comment: That worked thanks! But how can I open it in a small window? Like a pop-up

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<td><a href=\"edit.php?id=$row[id]\" target='_blank'>Edit</a></td>"
```

another way is write a js function open_window = function(){your stuff} and

```
echo "<td><a href=\"edit.php?id=$row[id]\" onclick='open_window()'>Edit</a></td>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `window.open` javascript functoin. Here is an example:

`<a href="#" onclick='javascript:window.open(url, "", "width=200, height=100");' >Edit</a>`

You may want to specify the javascript code in a separate function as well.

See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp for more information on window.open function.